# base64 encoding of byte array in javascript

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to do the reverse encode of a script that I'm using. I have the decode function. I now have to create the encode function, and I'm struggling a bit, where it details

```
"chr2 = (enc2 >> 2) | ((enc3 & 0x0F) << "
```

I'm not sure exactly what this means, or how to ensure that the encoded data is padded correctly.

I'm using the decodeAsArray function, to turn into a byte array and that works just fine. Now just trying to do vice-versa, the opposite way to encode the base64, so I'm hoping to create a encodeFromArray function, where I give a byte array as the input to the function.

```
Base64 = {
        _keyStr: ".ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+=",
        decode: function( input ) {
                    var output = "";
                    var hex = "";
                    var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
                    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
                    var i = 0;
                    var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\.\=]/g;

                    do {
                        enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
                        enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
                        enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
                        enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;

                        chr1 = (enc1 | ((enc2 & 3) << 6));                                                                                                             
                        chr2 = (enc2 >> 2) | ((enc3 & 0x0F) << 4);                                                                                                     
                        chr3 = (enc3 >> 4) | (enc4 << 2);


                        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);
                        if (enc3 != 64) {
                            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
                        }
                        if (enc4 != 64) {
                            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
                        }
                        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
                        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
                    } while (i < input.length);

                    return (output);
                },

    decodeAsArray: function (b) {
        var d = this.decode(b),
            a = [],
            c;
        for (c = 0; c < d.length; c++) {
            a[c] = d.charCodeAt(c)
        }
        return a
    }
```

I think it would look something like the following:

```
    encode : function (input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;


    while (i < input.length) {


        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);


        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
            enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
            enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

    }

    return output;
}
```

However, I'm not sure how the enc2, enc3 and enc4 should be, based on the decode function, and then I'm also not sure how to do it from byte array

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: how to base64 encode a byte array based on the decode function given...

Comment: There are many questions here on how to do base64 encode and decode in JS. Some of them are listed in the **Related** sidebar.

Comment: None of those show me how to encode, based on the decode function I have given...

Comment: Why does it have to be based on your decode function? Any base64 encoder should be equivalent.

Comment: Take a look at the code Barmar. It's specifically related to the enc variables...

Comment: The variables don't matter, that's just an implementation detail. Base64 is base64, how you calculate it is irrelevant.

Comment: It's to do with the padding that is being used. The encode example function I gave is from a different script. I'm trying to make it fit with the decode function.

Comment: Is this decoding something different from the standard base64 format? Because if it's the standard format, then any encoder should be compatible with the decoder.

Comment: The encoding is not different. It's the padding and bit-shifting that are different, which is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: The padding and bit-shifting are just this function's way of decoding it. You can use any encoding function as long as it produces the same encoding. So just find a function in one of the other questions and use it.

Comment: But it will be the same encoding with different padding and bit shifting, which is not what Im looking for. Im looking for the same encoding, with the same padding and bit shifting.

Comment: If it's different padding and bit shifting, it won't get the same encoding. The padding and bit shifting is used to produce the encoding, so it has to be the same.

Comment: Yes, that's my question. How to produce the same padding and bit-shifting as in the decode example...

Comment: I don't think we're understanding each other. All base64 encoding and decoding functions should produce the same results.

Comment: YEs, sorry for the confusion. I think it's because I mentioned base64 encoding, when the question has little to do witht this. I'm looking for the reverse of the bit shifiting process.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the original encodings as these bits. The top 2 bits of each encoding are `00` because there are only 63 characters in base64 encoding, and that only requires 6 bits.

```
enc1 = 00abcdef
enc2 = 00ghijkl
enc3 = 00mnopqr
enc4 = 00stuvwx
```

The bit-shifting then produces:

```
chr1 = (enc1 | ((enc2 & 3) << 6)) = 00abcdef | 000000kl << 6         = klabcdef                                                   
chr2 = (enc2 >> 2) | ((enc3 & 0x0F) << 4) = 0000ghij | 0000opqr << 4 = opqrghij                                                                                                   
chr3 = (enc3 >> 4) | (enc4 << 2) = 000000mn | stuvwx00               = stuvwxmn
```

So to reverse it, you need to do:

```
enc1 = chr1 & 0x3F;
enc2 = ((chr2 & 0x0F) << 2) | (chr1 >> 6);
enc3 = ((chr3 & 0x03 << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
enc4 = chr3 >> 2;
```

So it looks like you had the correct formulas, but you were doing them backwards -- your `enc1` is actually `enc4`.

Comment: Hi Barmar, just wondering what the reverse of the decode function is? Is the decode function working with 4 bit codes?

Comment: Just do these bit shifts in a loop, concatenating the results into a string.

Comment: Oops, I just realized that I was showing the reverse of your proposed encode function, not the reverse of the original decode function. I need to redo the answer.